# Deleting an entire row in Excel using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need a code the deletes the first row in a CSV file (the row is also empty).  I am using the code below to get the CSV file I need and delete tne content in the first cell, which is "users". But when I delete the content the cell remains empty. What I need is either a way to delete the whole row or maybe shift the entire column up after deleting "users"? Don't know if that works...

```
Get-Content C:\TEMP\test\File1.csv |
    % { $_ -replace 'users', '' } |
    Set-Content C:\TEMP\test\file2.csv
```

Comment: `Get-Content input.csv | Select-Object -Skip 1 |  Set-Content output.csv`

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete a **row** and not a **column** (_ I need to delete the content in the first cell, which is "users"_)? Show us part of your csv file, the first two or three lines would be enough. Make sure you change the real names, email addresses and such to fake ones before [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55218099/edit) your question.

Comment: thank you for the reply @Theo, the one-liner above did the trick just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but i think what you want is to remove the first **column** (users) of the `File1.csv` file and output a new csv file with all columns, except this `users` columns.

Suppose your input csv file (file1.csv) looks something like this:

```
"users","email","morestuff"
"John Doe","john.doe@yourcompany.com","blah"
"Jane Doe","jane.doe@yourcompany.com","more blah"
```

and what you want to do is remove the `users` column so file2.csv will become this:

```
"email","morestuff"
"john.doe@yourcompany.com","blah"
"jane.doe@yourcompany.com","more blah"
```

then this one-liner should do it:

```
(Import-Csv -Path 'C:\TEMP\test\file1.csv' | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Users) | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\TEMP\test\file2.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```